# Google Maps doesn't appear and always flickering in my flutter app

Tags: android, api, flutter, dart, maps

My Google maps don't appear in may page, and if I trying to open another page ex: opening my profile page, it's starts flickering and nothing appears.

I need to show the maps:

[image: Here's the output pic]

My Maps code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import
'package:galon_app/widget/header.dart'; import
'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {   @override   _MapsState
createState() => _MapsState(); }

class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {

Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();   static
const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);   final
Set<Marker> markers = {};   LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;  
MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

_onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
    _controller.complete(controller);   }

__onCameraMove(CameraPosition position){
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;   }

@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: header(context,title: 'Maps',removeAutomaticlyButton: true),
        body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: _center,
                    zoom: 11.0
                 ),
                    mapType: _currentMapType,
                    markers: markers,
                    onCameraMove: __onCameraMove,
                )
            ],
        ),
        );   
} }
```

And here's my home code:

```
**import 'package:galon_app/PlugIn/User.dart';
import 'package:galon_app/pages/maps.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:galon_app/pages/createUser.dart';
import 'NotifOrder.dart';
import 'OnGoingOrder.dart';
import 'Profile.dart';

final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
final userRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
final itemnRef = Firestore.instance.collection('item');
final priceRef = Firestore.instance.collection('prices');
User currentUser;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  final int pageIndex;

  Home({
    this.pageIndex
  });

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isAuth = false;
  PageController pageController;
  int pageIndex = 0;

  TextEditingController usernmae = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();


@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  setPageIndex();
  pageController = PageController(initialPage: pageIndex, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 1);

  //Checking is User Signed in
  googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account){
    handleSignIn(account);
  },onError: (err){
    print('Error singin: $err');
  }
  );

  //Reauthenticate user when app is opened
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account){
      handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err){
      print('Error Signin: $err');
    });
  
}
//Set page index
setPageIndex(){
  if(widget.pageIndex != null){
      pageIndex = widget.pageIndex;
      onPageChanged(pageIndex);
  }else{
      pageIndex = 0;
  }
}

//Login Handle
login(){
  googleSignIn.signIn();
}

logout(){
  googleSignIn.signOut();
}

handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account){
  if(account != null){
    setState(() {
      isAuth = true;
    });
  }else{
    setState(() {
      isAuth = false;
    });
  }
}

//Home Screen Handle 
  @override
void dispose() { 
  pageController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

//Set on page changed
onPageChanged(int pageIndex){
  setState(() {
    this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
  });
}

//Animated to next page when taped
onTap(int pageIndex){
  pageController.animateToPage(
    pageIndex,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut
  );
}
//Build UnAuthScreen(If user not logged in or havent sign up yet)
Scaffold buildUnAuthScreen(){
 return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        colors: [
          Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ]
      )
     ),child: Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         SizedBox(height: 150),
         Container(
           height: 150,
           width: 150,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Image.asset('assets/galonku_Logo.png'),
         ),
         SizedBox(height:500),
         GestureDetector(
            onTap: login,
            child: Container(
              width: 260,
              height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/googleSignIn_button.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                )
              )
            )
          )
       ],
     ),
   )
 ); 
}

//Build AuthScreen (If user already loggedin)
Scaffold buildAuthScreen(){
  return Scaffold(
    body: PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Maps(),
        //OnGoingOrder(),
        NotifOrder(),
        Profile(), 
      ],
      controller: pageController ,
      onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
      currentIndex: pageIndex,
      onTap: onTap,
      activeColor: Colors.grey[100],
      inactiveColor: Colors.grey[700],
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person))
      ],
    )
  );
}  

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return isAuth? buildAuthScreen() :buildUnAuthScreen();
}
}**
```

Comment: Check the API KEY, if you have done it correctly or not